# SfCalendar special dates background customization in MAUI

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui, sfcalendar

In my maui application I'm using sfcalendar and adding few special dates on that calendar. Currently am able to set bg color and text style for the special dates . But I want to show the special dates in the calendar inside a circle, like the below image.

[image: Expected UI]

But my code is not working like the above image. Current UI and code.

```
`  calendarcontrol.MonthView = new CalendarMonthView()
        {
            SpecialDayPredicate = (date) =>
            {
                if (SpecialDateLists.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in SpecialDateLists)
                    {
                        if (item.Date == date.Date)
                        {
                            CalendarIconDetails calendarIconDetails = new CalendarIconDetails();
                            calendarIconDetails.Icon = CalendarIcon.Square;
                            calendarIconDetails.Fill = Color.FromArgb("#72a951");
                            return calendarIconDetails;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            },
            SpecialDatesBackground = Color.FromArgb("#EAEDED"),
          
        };
```

[image: Current UI]